# Частица "то" в предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь

Очень часто слышу в последнее время (может быть раньше не обращала внимания) фразы типа: "Он сказал то, что я ему изменила", "Я понял то, что она мне нравится". и так далее. Мне кажется, частица "то" здесь ни к чему или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Только не частица, а указательное местоимение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Я понял то, что она мне нравится" звучит нормально,если это ответ на вопрос: Что ты понял? А вот в фразе "Он сказал то, что я ему изменила" явно "то" лишнее,не по-русски, как вместо "я студент" сказали бы "я есть студент". Утяжеление фразы лишними членами предложения, когда в языке идёт , наоборот, процесс упрощения, экономии языковых средств.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что носители русского языка стали путать две разные конструкции: А) Я понял,  что она мне нравится – придаточное изъяснительное, союз ЧТО не является членом предложения. Б) Я понял ТО, ЧТО все уже  давно знали – придаточное дополнительное, союзное слово ЧТО является членом предложения, указательное слово ТО обязательно.   В то же время и в придаточном изъяснительном возможно присутствие указательного слова, но  оно должно быть обоснованным, а не излишним.  Для сравнения: Он сомневался (в чем?) в том, что она ему нравится – придаточное изъяснительное, союз ЧТО, указательное слово В ТОМ.

По-моему, предложение "Я понял то, что она мне нравится" в любом случае звучит не лучшим образом. Что ты понял? Я понял, что она мне нравится. Зачем здесь указательное слово ТО?